# angular input formatter/parser directive and interpolated attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to write a configurable directive that is applied to an input element, which requires ngModel, and which adds a parser and a formatter function for ngModel.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to pass interpolated values into the directive while simultaneously supporting ngModel binding. For instance, I want to be able to use my directive in one of two ways:

passing literal arguments:

```
<input ng-model="foo" my-directive="120" />
```

or passing interpolated arguments from the current scope:

```
<input ng-model="foo" my-directive="{{bar}}" />

...
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.bar = "120";
}
```

If I read the attributes argument of the link function in my directive definition, I can get the value of attributes.myDirective in the first usage, but in the second usage the value of myDirective is undefined.

Now, if I add an isolated scope to the directive definition:

```
scope: { myDirective: '@' }
```

Then scope.myDirective is defined and interpolated in the scenarios above, but now ngModel is broken. My parser/formatter functions are passed undefined for their input arguments. What's going on, and how can I implement the behavior I want?

directive:

```
module.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            replace: false,
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) { // attrs.myDirective not interpolated
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your directive? My hunch is that you may not be using the `require` key, which will give you access to the `ngModel` controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the isolate scope, you're creating brand-new child scope that doesn't inherit from the scope with the `ngModel`'s value in it. That's why your parsers and formatters are getting undefined.

Also, in your example, to get at the value of `bar`, you don't need it in curly braces:

```
<input ng-model='foo' my-directive='bar' />
```

And in your linking function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
  attr.myDirective == 'bar'.
  scope.$eval(attr.myDirective) == // whatever the value of 'bar' is in the current scope
}
```

So you don't need the isolate scope. Just use `scope.$eval` to evaluate the expression passed to your directive.

[Here's a quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAkQs/).